# How to put custom style on dynamic created view

Tags: android, view, coding-style, programmatically-created

I have a problem with styling a dynamic created button in my android app. The way I'm doing it is to create the button from it's constructor:

> Button myButton = new Button(this,
>   null, R.style.Frontpage_case);

My problem is that the button layout disappears, but the text is still shown?
Is there an other way to accomplish dynamic buttons with different styles?

Comment: can you past the Frontpage_case style , your problem might be in the inheriting parent style